# Visual studio 2010 and SAP crystal reports app crash

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crash

I developed a C# (Visual Studio 2010) application in .NET Framework 4.0 in conjunction with SAP Crystal Reports Support Pack 9

When I deployed my application on Client computer I faced the following error after my application crash

> Faulting application name: TrackingApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x537a1687
>
> Faulting module name: cslibu-3-0.dll, version: 13.0.9.1312, time stamp: 0x53393fe8
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
>
> Fault offset: 0x00039a28
>
> Faulting process id: 0xf00
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01cf7376d8df092d
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Tracking System\Tracking System\TrackingApp.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\cslibu-3-0.dll
>
> Report Id: 24b4faea-df6a-11e3-8422-d067e51beb2a

The client has Windows 7 32-bit on his system.

During testing I found there are two reports which made my application crash. These two reports contains sub reports. While other reports are simple reports with no sub reports. While checking these two reports I found that when I open (view using report viewer) my reports first time they work absolutely fine but when I close the report and re-open it second time the app crashes.

Further I found when I open the other reports except these two faulty reports and then I open faulty reports they work fine and I can re-open multiple times

What should be the issue. My code is in try catch block but it did not generate any exception

```
this.Text = ApplicationConstants.APPTITLE + " - Print Delivery Note";
rptDeliveryNote objRpt = new rptDeliveryNote();
string deliveryNoteNumber = Convert.ToString(dtReport.Rows[0]["DeliveryNote_Number"]);
DataTable dtDeliveryNoteItems = CaseDAL.DNGetItemsByDNNumber(deliveryNoteNumber).Tables[0];
objRpt.SetDataSource(dtReport);
objRpt.Subreports["rptDeliveryNoteItems"].SetDataSource(dtDeliveryNoteItems);
rptViewer.ReportSource = objRpt;
```

Comment: instead of converting the report row to a string have you tried casting the Object as a string for example `string deliveryNoteNumber = (string)dtReport.Rows[0]["DeliveryNote_Number"].ToString()`